# ToggleSwitch in the WP8

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm writing WP8 app in the VS2013 and I want to add `ToggleSwitch` to my mobile app. To achieve that I clicked "Manage NuGet Packages" (the latest version installed) on my project and chose `Windows Phone Toolkit`. I have the following XAML code:

```
    xmlns:tool="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
<ToggleSwitch x:Name="toggleSwitch1" Header="ToggleSwitch" 
              OnContent="On" OffContent="Off" 
              Toggled="ToggleSwitch_Toggled"/>
```

And the errors are:
1) `The tag 'ToggleSwitch' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'.`
2) `The name "ToggleSwitch" does not exist in the namespace "http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007".`

Also on the WP page the following using statement `using Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit;` gets an error: `The type or namespace name 'Toolkit' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Phone.Controls' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have installed Nuget Package Properly then below code should run Perfectly.

```
        xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
         <toolkit:ToggleSwitch x:Name="ToggleSwitch" Header="Toggle Switch" IsChecked="false" Content="Content Goes here" Checked="switch_Checked" Unchecked="switch_Unchecked"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use your namespace identifier as a prefix in your element call. Like this

```
<tool:ToggleSwitch x:Name="toggleSwitch1" Header="ToggleSwitch" 
          OnContent="On" OffContent="Off" 
          Toggled="ToggleSwitch_Toggled"/>
```

That should fix your problem.